# Como aprimorar este algoritmo?

Tags: visualg, revisão-de-código, portugol

O objetivo do meu algoritmo é fazer o usuário treinar divisão: ele terá que acertar 10 vezes seguidas o quociente **inteiro** (isto é, sem casas decimais) e o resto da divisão. Eu fiz esse algoritmo especialmente para minha sobrinha, para ela passar no teste de seleção de um colégio chamado Colégio Santa Isabel. Caso ela acerte tudo, dou 3 biscoitos de recompensa a ela, caso não, ela tentará até acertar 10 vezes seguidas.

Dito isso, existiria alguma forma de aprimorar meu algoritmo? Obrigado desde já.

```
algoritmo "Divisão Adrya"
// Função : Treinar Adrya para a prova do Colégio Santa Isabel
// Autor : Rodrigo Matos Aguiar
// Data : 21/10/2016
// Seção de Declarações 
var
   NS1, NS2, NL, C, Q, VR, R, Fa: Inteiro // NS1 - Número Sorteado 1, NS2 - Número Sorteado 2, NL - Número Lido, C - Contador, Q - Quociente
   // VR - Valor do Resto, R - Resto, Fa - Falhou
inicio
// Seção de Comandos
Para C de 1 ate 10 faca
   NS1 <- Randi(100)
   NS2 <- Randi(100)
   EscrevaL("Calcule o quociente entre ", NS1, " e ", NS2, " (Maior pelo menor): ")
   Leia(Q)
   EscrevaL("Calcule o resto dessa divisão: ")
   Leia(R)
   Se (NS1 > NS2) entao
      VR <- NS1 % NS2
   senao
        VR <- NS2 % NS1
   FimSe
   Se (NS1 > NS2) entao
      Se (VR = 0) entao
         Se (Q = NS1 / NS2) entao
            Se (R = NS1 % NS2) entao
               EscrevaL("Você acertou tudo Adrya, parabéns!!!")
            senao
                 EscrevaL("Você acertou o quociente, mas errou o resto, foi quase lá!!!")
            FimSe
         senao
           EscrevaL("Você errou Adrya, presta atenção hein...")
           Fa <- Fa + 1
         FimSe
      senao
           Se (Q = (NS1 - VR) / NS2) entao
              Se (R = NS1 % NS2) entao
                 EscrevaL("Você acertou tudo Adrya, parabéns!!!")
              senao
                   EscrevaL("Você acertou o quociente, mas errou o resto, foi quase lá!!!")
              FimSe
           senao
                EscrevaL("Você errou Adrya, presta atenção hein...")
                Fa <- Fa + 1
           FimSe
      FimSe
   senao
        Se (VR = 0) entao
           Se (Q = NS2 / NS1) entao
              Se (R = NS2 % NS1) entao
                 EscrevaL("Você acertou tudo Adrya, parabéns!!!")
              senao
                   EscrevaL("Você acertou o quociente, mas errou o resto, foi quase lá!!!")
              FimSe
           senao
                EscrevaL("Você errou Adrya, presta atenção hein...")
                Fa <- Fa + 1
           FimSe
        senao
             Se (Q = (NS2 - VR) / NS1) entao
                Se (R = NS2 % NS1) entao
                   EscrevaL("Você acertou tudo Adrya, parabéns!!!")
                senao
                     EscrevaL("Você acertou o quociente, mas errou o resto, foi quase lá!!!")
                FimSe
             senao
                  EscrevaL("Você errou Adrya, presta atenção hein...")
                  Fa <- Fa + 1
             FimSe
        FimSe
   FimSe
FimPara
Se (Fa = 0) entao
   EscrevaL("Parabéns Adrya, você é fera em matemática! E ganhará 3 biscoitos!!!!!")
senao
   EscrevaL("Que pena Adrya, sem biscoito pra você. Se quiser ganhar os biscoitos, tente novamente e acerte todas as somas!!!!!")
FimSe
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Cookies! Gostei da gamificação do ensino, se funcionar, sua sobrinha será uma moça feliz que aprendeu a dividir!

Answer (score 2):

Poderia alterar de:

```
NS1 <- Randi(100)
NS2 <- Randi(100)
```

Para:

```
NS1 <- Randi(100)
NS2 <- Randi(NS1)
```

Assim não precisaria validar se um é maior que o outro além de facilitar o entendimento para o usuário.