# Gamificação é a mesma coisa que competição?

Tags: terminologia, gamificação

A gamificação é definida assim:

> é a estratégia de interação entre pessoas e empresas com base no oferecimento de incentivos que estimulem o engajamento do público com as marcas de maneira lúdica. [Fonte](https://exame.abril.com.br/pme/o-que-e-gamification/)

De fato esse conceito na construção de software está cada vez mais presente:

- o StackExchange o promove com medalhas, votos, pontos, privilégios em todas as suas comunidades;
- o Duolingo com pontuações e rankings.

Isso prova  a relação direta da gamificação com a competição como forma de engajamento.

O que difere a gamificação da competição a fim de cativar um público?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nem sempre. Tornar lúdico através da competição é uma das opções disponíveis. Sendo sincero, eu sou competitivo, portanto eu sou facilmente fisgado por essa isca.

Se na gamificação escolhida o sistema de pontos não for aberto, então não vai ter competição externa. Será apenas você e o ponto subindo no sistema.

O mesmo pensamento vale para as *badges*.

Um sistema não competitivo (por natureza de competição pura) é o esquema de votos positivos aqui na rede SE para **perguntas**. Puramente, é um sistema de feedback em um jogo social para saber se sua interação foi bem quista ou não. O bom e velho karma do Orkut também não era competitivo, apesar de ser uma pontuação gamificada.

### Exemplos de gamificação não competitiva

- *quests*: algum tipo de interação por tempo limitado, levando a recompensa
- votos: o sistema de votos em um jogo social por si só não é um fator direto para concorrência, principalmente quando não é colocado como contraponto

  - aqui na rede SE, o sistema de votos em pergunta eu vejo como não competitivo, já os de respostas... quem não sonha em ter uma resposta mais bem aceita que uma do Maniero?  ;-)
- *achievements*/*badges*/pontuação privado: se você não enxerga os *achievements* de outras pessoas, como você vai tentar competir com elas?
- combo: do DuoLingo mesmo o exemplo, você pode fazer um combo de estudar tantos dias consecutivos
- recompensa/pontos: no *landing.jobs*, você ganha recompensa se não me engano pela indicação que gerou contratação. Monetária. Em outros sistemas a recompensa é mais tímida e abstrata, como pontos arbitrários
- barra de progresso: o próprio exibidor de progresso do quanto você escreveu no LinkedIn sobre si mesmo; quem em sã consciência não desejaria um 100%?

---

Acabei de ver um exemplo real de gamificação não competitiva. Foi posta como uma pergunta aqui no site: [Como aprimorar este algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160563/64969)

Nesse exemplo, não há competição. Alguns falarão que saber dividir para ganhar cookies é um condicionamento baseado nas técnicas de Skinner, mas na visão do jogador (a sobrinha do AP comedora de cookies) isso é um jogo.

Comment: É como algo para superar algo que você mesmo já tenha. Não é bem uma competição, é um desafio. Interessante.

Comment: @vnbrs no curso de jogos, meu coordenador chama gamificação de design motivacional. Acabei de me lembrar  do _zombie's run_, um app desses de fitness que você corre e, se ficar mais lento do que um limite, você ouve a horda se aproximando

Comment: é possível gamificar uma aplicação utilizando recompensas que mantém o usuário motivado mas sem que necessariamente exista uma competição com outros usuários ativos, apesar de que a competição ser um artefato interessante dentro da gamificação em si.

Comment: @rodrigorf exatamente! Tem gente que prefere chamar de design motivacional no lugar de gamificação

Comment: badges é um sistema pseudo-competivo, que quando comparados se torna  
 competivo

Comment: @HudsonPH na ótica social do "eu tenho, você não tem", Badgers visíveis geram competição. Assim como o simples esquema de pontuação visível. Esquema competitivo puro mesmo seriam _leaderboards_.

Answer (score 19):

### TL;DR

> Gamificação é a mesma coisa que competição?

Definitivamente esses conceitos **não são** a mesma coisa. A competição é um elemento que pode ser utilizado em um processo gamificado, mas não é o único elemento interessante ou necessário.

### Gamificação

Um dos primeiros estudos de gamificação de forma científica foi realizado por [Deterding et al. em 2011](http://gamification-research.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/02-Deterding-Khaled-Nacke-Dixon.pdf) (o termo entrou na moda por volta de 2010). Para esses autores, a definição de gamificação é:

> Gamificação é o uso de elementos do projeto de jogos em contextos que
>   não são jogos.
>
> Tradução livre do original em inglês: *Gamification is the use of game design elements in non-game contexts*.

Isso quer dizer que podemos utilizar técnicas e ferramentas tradicionalmente utilizadas para se construir jogos no projeto de qualquer produto (software ou não) cuja intenção **primária** não seja o entretenimento. E por que alguém faria isso? Porque, diferentemente daquele seu trecho de código que você manda executar e ele obedece, humanos precisam ser *motivados* a agir de alguma forma - e a diversão é um grande motivador intrínseco (por intrínseco entenda que não depende de benefícios externos óbvios como dinheiro, comida, promessa de ganhos futuros, etc).

### Ok, mas e a Competição?

Acontece que esse assunto é complexo. A própria definição de gamificação tem uma fronteira muito nebulosa, principalmente porque definir o que é jogo também é difícil (se tiver interesse, leia a respeito da rixa entre [Narratologistas e Ludologistas](http://www.sbgames.org/papers/sbgames09/culture/full/cult21_09.pdf)). Eu gosto da definição de Deterding et al. principalmente quando ela é considerada juntamente com o trabalho de [Fullerton](https://www.crcpress.com/Game-Design-Workshop-A-Playcentric-Approach-to-Creating-Innovative-Games/Fullerton/p/book/9781482217162):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem acima é baseada nos dois trabalhos citados. A ideia de Deterding et al. é que existem dois eixos que definem os diferentes tipos de produtos/tarefas que utilizam técnicas de design de jogos. O eixo horizontal, chamado "Todo-Parte", indica se o produto/tarefa é considerado como um todo (isto é, como algo único ou monolótico) ou em partes (isto é, composto de coisas ou atividades menores). O eixo vertical, chamado "Brincar-Jogar", indica a intenção do usuário ao utilizar o produto ou realizar a tarefa.

A contribuição de Fullerton no detalhamento do eixo vertical demonstra que o nível de interação auxilia ainda mais nessa classificação: a interação não envolve apenas tocar e mover, mas também esforço cognitivo necessário para reconhecer um objetivo e planejar as ações necessárias para alcançá-lo. Assim, quanto mais interação é necessária, mais próximo um produto/tarefa está de um jogo; quanto menos interação, mais próximo está de uma mera narrativa (um livro, um filme ou uma peça de teatro, por exemplo).

É claro que essa definição é discutível, mas ela me parece útil para entendermos que Gamificação trata-se de utilizar esses conceitos de design para intimamente construir tarefas compostas por várias partes, mas que tenham não somente um objetivo como uma condição de vitória (importantes do ponto de vista do utilizador). Outra coisa clara nessa definição é que um processo gamificado é bem distinto de um jogo para entretenimento, e também de um "jogo sério": um jogo (um produto "Todo") que é utilizado com um propósito diferente do mero entretenimento (como, por exemplo, quando jogos do *Wii Motion* são utilizados para ajudar na fisioterapia).

A competição pode fazer parte em qualquer desses tipos de produtos, até mesmo em brinquedos/brincadeiras. Mesmo sem ter um objetivo ou condição de vitória, uma brincadeira ainda pode envolver competição em outros aspectos, como em ter o brinquedo mais bonito (vide qualquer interação com brinquedos entre os personagens Chaves e Quico na TV) ou ser o mais capaz de detalhar a narrativa ou fantasia envolvidos na brincadeira.

De todas as formas, adicionar medalhas e listas de pontuações somente é interessante se o utilizador percebe isso como algo valioso para si, e - principalmente - se pode comparar sua pontuação com outros utilizadores para poder experienciar emoções relacionadas à competição (como foi bem colocado pela resposta aceita).

### Mas, então, o que há além da Competição?

A complexidade do assunto não para na definição do que é jogo. Também é difícil definir o que é diversão e o que a produz. A competição é certamente um elemento importante na diversão porque envolve desafios (oportunidades de ação que permitam alcançar um objetivo difícil, porém factível), mas não é o único elemento e tampouco é sempre necessária. Esse caráter é um dos mais fáceis de se medir em um jogo. Por exemplo, em um jogo de corrida eu poderia medir o número de vezes que o jogador bateu o carro ou se atrasou, e utilizar essa medida "utilitária" para tentar saber se o jogador está sendo capaz de competir ou não. Se eu concluir que ele está indo muitíssimo mal na competição, eu poderia inferir que ele não está se divertindo? Essa pergunta já foi feita por muita gente, e a resposta parece ser **não**. Afinal, o jogador pode estar batendo o carro de propósito, aproveitando o passeio e se deslumbrando com os efeitos gráficos das batidas, de modo que se perguntado talvez dissesse que estava se divertido muitíssimo!

Enfim, há muitos outros aspectos que são importantes além do desafio (relacionado à competição). Há centenas de estudos, mas [Malone](https://www.learning-theories.com/intrinsically-motivating-instruction-malone.html), por exemplo, afirma que os aspectos importantes são Desafio (oportunidades de ação e objetivos claros), Curiosidade (informação sensorial nova e diferente, porém não completamente caótica) e Fantasia (imagens mentais que ajudam a compreender o mundo real ou fictício). O tal [modelo MDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDA_framework) (uma das referências mais conhecidas na área) já evoluiu isso pra outros aspectos, incluindo o aspecto social, de exploração (do mundo e do eu), e até mesmo o mero esforço pra gastar tempo (que os autores chamaram de "submissão").

Mas, você quer ter uma visão bem resumida (e fantástica) sobre o que realmente está "em jogo" (*pun intended*) além da competição? Então dá uma estudada num outro modelo chamado [*The 4 Keys 2 Fun*](http://www.nicolelazzaro.com/the4-keys-to-fun/), da [Nicole Lazzaro](https://www.linkedin.com/in/nicolelazzaro/). A seguir eu reproduzo a imagem do modelo da Nicole (os direitos são todos da autora, eu reproduzo aqui em *fair use* apenas com a inteção de divulgação do conhecimento e do trabalho da autora, que está livremente acessível no site referenciado acima). Vale muito também acessar o blog da autora, ler seus trabalhos e, principalmente, assistir [sua palestra no TED Talks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CyPq1uwrRAc).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você vai perceber, esse modelo indica que a competição (que envolve a busca por vencer desafios, seja sozinho - contra si mesmo - ou em grupo - contra outros) é apenas parte da diversão. Há também o aspecto social (interagir com outras pessoas, criar laços afetivos, e passar tempo com os amigos), o aspecto da curiosidade (permitir a exploração de fantasias e a satisfação da imaginação) e o aspecto do propósito (pensar, sentir e se comportar de forma a fazer a diferença no mundo e na vida de outras pessoas).

Na sua pergunta você diz:

> "Isso prova a relação direta da gamificação com a competição como
>   forma de engajamento"

Eu diria que isso prova que a competição tem sua função. Além de motivar certos tipos de pessoas pela competição, os votos do StackOverflow também têm um caráter [estigmértico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estigmergia) ao fazer com que conteúdo com mais votos (positivos ou negativos) atraiam cada vez mais atenção e consequentemente tendam a ganhar mais votos. Porém, um website ou uma terefa que deva ser gamificada deve buscar também outros aspectos para a motivação das pessoas, explorando suas emoções também com laços sociais, com elementos visuais e sonoros curiosos, e por aí vai.

Comment: É uma pena que você tenha respondido só hoje. Enquanto que a minha resposta é superficial feita para atender a dúvida específica, mas você conseguiu fazer um tratado sobre o assunto. Muito obrigado por essa resposta

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Ah, puxa, eu só consegui tempo pra responder hoje. :/ Obrigado, mas a sua resposta também é muito boa ao tocar em certos assuntos (mesmo que de forma intuitiva). Por exemplo, quando diz: "*se você não enxerga os achievements de outras pessoas, como você vai tentar competir com elas?*" você toca exatamente num ponto importante pra fazer uma competição bem feita (quando é a intenção de ter competição, claro): feedback. E, de certa forma, também trata do caráter social que é muito importante. :)